# Windows Server 2008 DNS server CNAME resolution and TTLs

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, cname-record, mx-record

We have a Windows 2008 SP2 DNS server configured to use root hints.  We have a certain MX record lookup that it periodically fails to resolve for our client machines.

The lookup is for the MX record for `mydomain.com`, which should resolve to `mydomain-com.mail.eo.outlook.com`.

Periodically our DNS server returns SERVFAIL error indicating it cant resolve the A record for `mydomain-com.mail.eo.outlook.com`.

From my research, it appears to be related to the different TTL values of the MX record, and the A record.  The MX record has a TTL of 3600, the A record has a TTL of 60.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?  Where the A record expires before the CNAME does, and causes your DNS server to return SERVFAIL error when attempting to resolve a MX record?  Various technet articles recommend either enabling DNS forwarders, or decreasing your MaxCacheTTL entry.  I simply dont understand why these would correct the issue? Why would the DNS server not just use root hints to lookup the A record again?

[LINK: Technet article describing similar issue](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/winserverNIS/thread/b00fc041-ba44-45b6-a8a1-a00374a20edf)